# sed uncomment multiple lines using variables in bash

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have the following problem: I'm trying to uncomment from a specific line that I determine using:

```
LINESTART=$(grep -nr "matching string" test.conf | cut -d : -f1)
```

After that I need to uncomment the portion of the code from that `$LINESTART` to `$((LINE+10))`

```
LINEEND=$((LINE+10))
```

I tried the following sed syntax:

```
sed -i '${LINESTART},${LINEEND} s/# *//' test.conf
```

But I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command
```

Example test.conf:

```
 84     #server {
 85     #    listen       8000;
 86     #    listen       somename:8080;
 87     #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;
 88 
 89     #    location / {
 90     #        root   html;
 91     #        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
 92     #    }
 93     #}
```

Comment: Note that bash variables like `${LINESTART}` aren't substituted with their values when within single quotes.

Comment: LINEEND=$((LINE+10)) should be changed to LINEEND=$((LINESTART+10))

Comment: btw, no need for `$LINEEND` - you can use `sed -i '${LINESTART},+10 ...` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

could you try this;

```
sed -i "${LINESTART},${LINEEND} s/# *//" test.conf
```

Test;

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINESTART=$(grep -nr "server {" test | cut -d : -f1 )
LINEEND=$((LINE+10))

sed "${LINESTART},${LINEEND} s/# *//" test
```

Output :

```
$ ./test.sh 
    server {
    listen       8000;
    listen       somename:8080;
    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

      location / {
      root   html;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      }
      }
```

Comment: LINEEND=$((LINE+10)) should be changed to LINEEND=$((LINESTART+10))

Answer (score 1):

Using shell variables within single quotes keeps them from being replaced with their values. Using double quotes instead should achieve what you want:

```
$ cat file
# a0
# a1
# a2
# a3

$ S=2
$ E=3

$ sed "${S},${E}s/# *//" file
# a0
a1
a2
# a3
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, just use awk for the whole thing:

```
$ awk '/location/{c=4} c&&c--{sub(/# */,"")} 1' file
 84     #server {
 85     #    listen       8000;
 86     #    listen       somename:8080;
 87     #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;
 88
 89     location / {
 90     root   html;
 91     index  index.php index.html index.htm;
 92     }
 93     #}
```

The command to find files btw is named `find`, not `grep -r`, and just like GNU sed has `-i` for inplace editing, GNU awk has `-i inplace` if you need it, so this may be what you really want:

```
$ find . -name 'file' -exec \
    awk -i inplace '/location/{c=4} c&&c--{sub(/# */,"")} 1' {} \;
```